# Error: Class extends value #<Object> is not a constructor or null, but not a circular dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance, requirejs, node-modules

[Error message in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpgha.png)
Error: `Class extends value #<Object> is not a constructor or null`

At first I thought I was getting this error due to a circular dependency, but I checked using madge and its saying there's no circular dependencies in the project. Both files are in the same folder as well.
[See a visualization of dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gF9bY.png)

Which led me to believe it was an error with importing, exporting, or the class itself. Can anyone offer any ideas as to what is going wrong. Thanks

Here's the full code (short)

*item.js*

```
class Item {
  constructor(name, description) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
  }
}

module.exports = { Item };
```

*food.js*

```
const Item = require('./item');

class Food extends Item {
  constructor(name, description) {
    super(name, description);
  }
}

module.exports = {
  Food,
};
```

Comment: The key thing I see is that you're exporting your class in an object. Use `module.exports = Item;` instead because your second script isn't destructuring anything from the import. Your code works for me when I did that.

Comment: Change to `module.exports = Item;` to make it compatible with `const Item = require('./item');`, or change to `const { Item } = require('./item');` to make it compatible to `module.exports = { Item };`.